# how to append data to csv file in groovy without using the append keyword

Tags: groovy

I'm having a null csv file in that I need to append some data . while I'm using append in my code it was not working.

Code I have tried:

```
def a = "F:\\abcd.csv" 
a. append("server list")
a. append("\n\r")
a. append("abcd.na.admworld.com")
```

While I'm using the above script it is not working

Comment: "it is not working" - **what** is not working? Please add the error message etc.

Comment: From the comments to the answers, it is clear, that your groovy version is either sand-boxed, old, or in any other way restricted. Without you telling us, what those restrictions are, this will most likely end up in more answers suggesting more obscure things, which may or may not work.  Please state the restriction, that is at play here, so we know what we have to work with, and don't have to guess.

Answer (score 1):

What you want can be done as one-liner (well with multiline string literal):

```
new File( "F:\\abcd.csv" ).text << '''server list
abcd.na.admworld.com'''
```

Comment: actually our workspace is not supporting the append function, delete function and readcsvfile function in groovy 

above you mentioned like new file right it will also will not work .

I literally don't know how to move further .



is there any chance like we can append in groovy without append 

I tried all the answers and provided the errors also.

Comment: What is your workspace, because those are all standard Goovy methods ?

Comment: that must be a DO NOT WORK space, as it allowes nothing

Comment: in that scenario what needs to be done .. do u have any idea like how we can append the content

Comment: you must elaborate on your "workspace" first. If it can not accept standard java/groovy methods, we cannot help you further

Answer (score 0):

Unlike for example Python, in Groovy you have to specify a file object. Try this:

```
def a = new File("F:\\abcd.csv")
a.append("server list")
a.append("\n\r")
a.append("abcd.na.admworld.com")
```

You also have spaces before `append` so just check your code.

If you want an alternative to `append` you can do this:

```
a << "server list"
a << "\n\r"
a << "abcd.na.admworld.com"
```

Comment: yes, I even tried in that way also but did not work.     is there any alternative for append in groovy

Comment: I updated my answer with what you want, however `append` should work unless you have some non-standard setup.

Comment: Thank you . I will try this and let u know the result. The thing is our workspace is not supporting the append function in groovy

Comment: > Unlike for example Python, in Groovy you have to specify a file object.  

I think python still  need a file object (or something alike)

Comment: a << "server list"
a << "\n\r"
a << "abcd.na.admworld.com"

I tried this got no errors but still it did not append the content into csv file.

can you let me know what needs to be done .

thanks in advance.